# How to create a hyperlink in a cell in Excel using Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, excel, visual-studio

I am trying to create a CV entry system where I need to save an image location in excel (i.e. create a hyperlink in one of the cell in excel) which will allow me to open the picture file directly from Excel.

```vb
Dim TextFile As String = "E:\Tests.xlsx"

If File.Exists(TextFile) Then
    File.Delete(TextFile)
End If

Dim oExcel As Object
oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim eBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim eSheet As Excel.Worksheet

eBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
eSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
' I want to create a hyperlink in a cell excel file to point at a image location in drive
eSheet.Name = "Test File"

eBook.SaveAs(TextFile)
eBook.Close()

eBook = Nothing


oExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that will help you to create hyperlink in excel file

```
Dim range As CellRange = sheet1.Range("C3")
Dim hyperlink1 As HyperLink = sheet1.HyperLinks.Add(range)
hyperlink1.Type = HyperLinkType.File
hyperlink1.TextToDisplay = "This is a hyperlink"
hyperlink1.Address = "employee2.xlsx"
```

Comment: not helping sir.  CellRange and Hyperlink is not defined. I guess i need to import something but i don't know what?